# I'm trying to create an Ad - Hoc bulid but failed

Tags: xcode

So I'm trying to create an Ad - Hoc bulid but after trying to export this archive, I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of try and edit the distribution profile and download it again then restart the xcode.

If that don't work then try this....

go to keychain access, -> Show Expired Certificates, and check your expired certificates and delete them from both the login and System keychains.

Then download a new one from https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and add it to and add it to Keychain access -> certificates